# Soundtest works, but no other sounds and windows starts very slowly

Tags: windows-xp, performance, audio, boot

So suddenly all sounds on my computer stopped working expect the sound test works, but when I go to control panel and audio it says there's no audio device. And audio players and audio on website doesn't work either. and Also windows starts very slowly.

I'm not sure if this helps but I'll tell what happened before this. I downloaded this program from a little shady website, I hesitated and for a good reason I guess cos the moment I finished downloading it, my antivir detected it as unwanted program and put it on quarantine. I thought everything was fine, but had some problems with program (won't go to details about it cos it's not really related to audio) so rebooted the computer and I was suprised that windows started really really slowly. It took like 5 mins to load the desktop such. After that I noticed the sounds were missing, I immediately deleted the program since I thought it was causing the problem. But it didn't change much.

I tried to find the solution with no success and now I'm just scanning again my computer. I'd be thankful if anyone would be able to help me. I might have left a thing or ten things out, so feel free to ask.

oh and I'm using windows xp

Comment: Rule #1: If you think you have a virus **DO NOT** restart your computer. For future reference...

Comment: Run a very good antivirus.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Care to list some suggestions?

Comment: I have Avira Antivirus

Comment: I use Microsoft Security Essentials and Malwarebytes.

Comment: I scanned again with AVG anti-virus. It found 10 threats of which most were deleted (1 was high threat level trojan) and those which it couldn't were 1 medium and 3 small level threats I deleted those by myself. Nothing changed though

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing I'd recommend is see if there's a recent system restore point you can restore to, and whether or not that makes this problem go away.

[How to restore Windows XP to a previous state](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084)

Edit: The Second thing I'd try is to use your Windows XP CD to perform a repair.

Comment: It might work. However, if it's a smart virus it will have already infected restore points.

Comment: Someone already suggested that and I tried it, didn't help